# Python: Dynamically inserting user defined data to 2 dimensional list

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I am attempting to create a table for weekly sales from a vendor, which looks like:

```
Monday    Tuesday    Wednesday    
50        80         10
54        98         7
29        40         80
```

I am trying to make the user insert the daily sales, here is what I have so far:

```
weekly_sales_list = [['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', []]]

    for i in range(len(weekly_sales_list)):
        for j in range(len(weekly_sales_list[i])):
            weekly_sales_list[i][j] = input('input value for ' + weekly_sales_list[i][j])
    print(weekly_sales_list)
```

I am not sure if this is the best way to setup a 2 dimensional list, and I am also receiving the following error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is the purpose of `weekly_sales`? The rest of the code never uses it.

Comment: It uses `weekly_sales_list`, you should put that in the question instead.

Comment: I think you want `for day_sales in weekly_sales_list`, you shouldn't be using `range(len(str(...)))`

Comment: There appears to be an indentation error in your posted code.

Comment: That's the least of the problems, and it's probably just a copying error.

Comment: My apologies, I have corrected the name of the list, however that didn't seem to solve the issue.

Comment: `weekly_sales_list[0][7]` is a list when `i`=0 and `j`=7 you are trying to concatenate the user input which is a `str` to the list - that is not possible as the Exception suggests.  ... [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary with the name of the week as the key and the data for that week as the value.

```
import itertools
data = {'Monday':[],
        'Tuesday':[],
        'Wednesday':[],
        'Thursday':[],
        'Friday':[],
        'Saturday':[],
        'Sunday':[]}
while 1:
    info = input('Enter day and value (e.g. "Monday 26") or nothing to stop: ')
    if not info:
        break
    k,v = info.split()
    data[k].append(v)
```

And then print a table by displaying the header:

```
print(*(f'{day:<10}' for day in data))
```

Finally, transpose your data, using `itertools.zip_longest` to handle days with fewer values than others:

```
for group in itertools.zip_longest(*data.values(), fillvalue=''):
    print(*(f'{value:<10}' for value in group))
```

Sample input:

```
Enter day and value (e.g. "Monday 26") or nothing to stop: Monday 3
Enter day and value (e.g. "Monday 26") or nothing to stop: Monday 4
Enter day and value (e.g. "Monday 26") or nothing to stop: Monday 5
Enter day and value (e.g. "Monday 26") or nothing to stop: Tuesday 6
Enter day and value (e.g. "Monday 26") or nothing to stop: Tuesday 7
Enter day and value (e.g. "Monday 26") or nothing to stop: Wednesday 8
Enter day and value (e.g. "Monday 26") or nothing to stop: Thursday 9
Enter day and value (e.g. "Monday 26") or nothing to stop:
```

Sample result:

```
Monday     Tuesday    Wednesday  Thursday   Friday     Saturday   Sunday
3          6          8          9
4          7
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Using lists as in your question, slight change the structure:

```
weekly_sales_list = [['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'],[]]
```

Define a method to collect data from user (`from random import randint` for simulation):

```
def ask_for_input(n):
  tmp = []
  for i in range(7):
      # user_input = input('input value for ' + weekly_sales_list[0][i])
      # print('input value for ' + weekly_sales_list[0][i])
      user_input = randint(0,2) # to simulate user input (from random import randint)
      tmp.append(user_input)
  weekly_sales_list[1].append(tmp)
```

Loop to ask user input:

```
for n in range(3):
  # print('week - ' + str(n) )
  ask_for_input(n)
```

Prepare data and the table for printing:

```
tot_per_day = [sum(col) for col in zip(*weekly_sales_list[1])]
tot_per_day = tot_per_day + [sum(tot_per_day)]
headers = weekly_sales_list[0] + ['total']
row_format ="{:>12}"*9
```

Then print out:

```
print (row_format.format("", *headers))
for row in weekly_sales_list[1]:
  print (row_format.format("", *(row + [sum(row)])))
print ("-"*12*9)
print (row_format.format("", *tot_per_day))
```

This is a random result:

```
# Monday     Tuesday   Wednesday    Thursday      Friday    Saturday      Sunday       total
#      0           1           1           0           2           0           1           5
#      1           2           0           2           0           0           1           6
#      1           2           0           0           1           0           2           6
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#      2           5           1           2           3           0           4          17
```